# Remove overlay image in cameraview

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiscrollview, uiimageview, uigesturerecognizer

I have imageview under scrollview. In imageview having images. When i click particular image from scrollview, the image is appear overlay of cameraview. I used doubleTap for removing overlay image. when i use doubleTap the overlay image removed from superview. After that, i display scrollview and select another image, the image won't appearing in cameraView (overlay)

code:

Gesture for doubleTap:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *doubletap=[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(doubleTap:)];
    doubletap.numberOfTapsRequired=2;
    [myImageView addGestureRecognizer:doubletap];

UITapGestureRecognizer *doubletap1=[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(doubleTap1:)];
    doubletap1.numberOfTapsRequired=2;
    [myImageView1 addGestureRecognizer:doubletap1];
```

Method for doubleTap:

```
-(void)doubleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer*)sender{

    NSLog(@"image");

    [myImageView removeFromSuperview];

}

-(void)doubleTap1:(UITapGestureRecognizer*)sender{

    NSLog(@"image1");

    [myImageView1 removeFromSuperview];

}
```

Add imageview to scrollview:

```
    -(void)unloadPreviousPage:(int)index
    {



        for(int i=index*4;i<(index+1)*4;i++)
        {
            [[myScrollView viewWithTag:i+1] removeFromSuperview];

        }


    }

-(void)loadNextPage:(int)index
{


    int countFlag=0;
    for(int i=index*4;i<(index+1)*4;i++)
    {
        UIButton *imageView=[[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake((320*index)+countFlag*80+ 2, 5, 75, 75)];
        imageView7.tag=i+1;
        [imageView7 addTarget:self action:@selector(imageViewClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        //[imageView.layer setBorderColor:[UIColor lightGrayColor].CGColor];
        // [imageView.layer setBorderWidth:1.0f];
        switch ((i+1)%2) {
            case 0:
                [imageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"img.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

                break;

            case 1:
                [imageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"img1.png"]  forState:UIControlStateNormal];

                break;
}

        [myScrollView addSubview:imageView];


        countFlag++;
    }
}

-(void)imageViewClicked:(id)sender{

    switch ([sender tag]%2) {
        case 0:
            [myImageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"img.png"]];
            break;

        case 1:
            [myImageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"img1.png"]];
            break;
}
}
```

Comment: Did you add imageview to overlayview again when you secondtime select image from scrollview??

Comment: See my edit code for add imageview to scrollview

Comment: You need to use Tag to remove object other wise need to refrence object

Comment: I have more than 50 images. Should use tag for all images?

Comment: When you doubletap you are removing imageview from overlayView and In -(void)imageViewClicked:(id)sender method you are assiging image to the imageview but imageview is already removed. So I think you have to add imageview again to the OverlayView In this method.

Comment: Yes. you are correct. How to add imageview again to overlayview?

Comment: Shall i use like this:                                        NSArray *subviews = [[myImageView subviews] copy];
for (UIView *subview in subviews) {
    [subview removeFromSuperview];
}

Comment: add this line [Overlayviewobj addSubView:myImageView]  at the end of -(void)imageViewClicked:(id)sender and try.

Comment: when i use [self.view addSubView:myImageView] some pan and pinch gesture is not working for that imageView

Comment: May be myImageView is added above all the gesture.In that case you can send it back using "sendSubViewToBack" method or  Another way is instead of removing the imageview you can hide it and at the time of image change you can show it. It may works.